# Background opacity modifier not applied

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I recently upgraded to tailwind 3 in my angular app (v13.0.3).

I'm trying to use the new [color opacity modifier for a background](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity), like this : `bg-primary-10/30` (primary is a custom color I defined) but it's not working the class seems to be unrecognized. I've tried with only bg-primary-10 and it works.
I've tried in the [tailwind playground app](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) and it works with the background opacity modifier.

Comment: try to disable purging for a moment and try if its working.

Comment: There's no purge in tailwind 3

Comment: they just renamed it https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/6019. But i guess the process is the same, they query your css and html files an removing every class thats not used by ur soruces. I guess the error sits there